# Debug user profiles?

Tags: development, profile-manager, configuration-profiles

There's an error in a user profile I'm generating to configure an wireless internet connection. When I try to import it the Profile Manager tells me there's an error, and if I try to use the [profiles](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/profiles.1.html) utility I get the following error:

```
$ profiles -v -I -F ./xxx.mobileconfig
profiles: verbose mode ON
profiles: using user name = xxx
profiles install profile xxx.mobileconfig for user: xxx
profiles install for file: 'xxx.mobileconfig' and user:'xxx' returned 3840 (The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)
profiles: returned error: 3840
fail
```

This is the error you get if you try to import any file that's not valid, from an .mp3 file to a proper .mobileconfig file with a missing closing tag, so it's not very helpful.

I've checked for obvious errors, like whether it's correct XML, whether there are any weird characters or whatever - didn't find anything. I've tried comparing it to a correct file but I haven't been able to find anything yet. Is there any way to get more detail about what's wrong? Some sort of tool, or at least a proper documentation about the format of these files? Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, I found the [specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html), I'm going to look into it.